# adding column values using awk

Tags: awk, ksh, gnu

Adding columns using awk:

```
x,y,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
m,z,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
a,b,206,1,0,2,0,0,0,0  
c,d,211,0,0,0,0,0,0,1  
e,f,8,0,0,1,0,0,0,0  
g,h,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
i,j,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
k,l,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
m,n,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
o,p,43,0,0,1,0,0,0,0  
q,r,2153,28,1,5,0,0,5,3  
s,t,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
u,v,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
x,y,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  
,,2799,29,1,9,0,0,5,4  

awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) sum[i]+=$i;}; END{for (i in sum) print sum[i];}' file1
```

but it's printing on newline.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: yep its printing on new line the output , not in same line seperated by comma

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: How about `... print $0, sum[i]`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @sam_84 is expected output  ,,2799,29,1,9,0,0,5,4   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try this;

this is sum rows and inserted the last of each line.

```
 awk -F, '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sum+= $i } print $0 "," sum}' file1
```

To sum columns,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i} END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf sum[i] OFS; printf "\n"}' file1
```

Test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i} END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf sum[i] OFS; printf "\n"}' file1
0,0,2799,29,1,9,0,0,5,4,


$ awk -F, '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sum+= $i } print $0 "," sum}' test
x,y,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8
m,z,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
a,b,206,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,209
c,d,211,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,212
e,f,8,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,9
g,h,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
i,j,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
k,l,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,36
m,n,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
o,p,43,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,44
q,r,2153,28,1,5,0,0,5,3,2195
s,t,96,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,96
u,v,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25
```

Comment: No its blank output its not displaying any results

Comment: the first one is not displaying results yet , tried using awk -F, no luck

Comment: sam_84, solutions provided by Mustafa working fine for me, so could you please check once if there are NO carriage characters please in your Input_file by doing cat -v Input_file?